# Capture directory value found with wildcard

Tags: vba, ms-access

Is there a way of storing the directory found when using a wildcard?  For example, if I have code that checks whether a directory exists:

```
Public Function DirectoryFinder(PartialFolderName As String)
     Dim FilePath As String
     If Dir(CurrentProject.Path & "\DataFolder\" & PartialFolderName & "*", vbDirectory)<>"" Then
          'FilePath = ???
     End If
End Function
```

Where the current project resides in C:\Folder and the desired full filepath is C:\Folder\DataFolder\PartialFolderName12345.

Is there a way to capture the directory found by the Dir() function within the FilePath variable?  If I define FilePath as the following, I don't believe it captures the directory found:

```
FilePath=CurrentProject.Path & "\DataFolder\" & PartialFolderName & "*"
```

Rather, it sets FilePath equal to the string "C:\Folder\DataFolder\PartialFolderName*", which doesn't work for what I need.

What I want to be able to capture is the full "C:\Folder\DataFolder\PartialFolderName12345"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
Sub Test()
    Dim MyPath As String
    MyPath = DirectoryFinder("SomeFolder123")
End Sub

Public Function DirectoryFinder(PartialFolderName As String) As String
     Dim FilePath As String
     FilePath = Dir(CurrentProject.Path & "\DataFolder\" & PartialFolderName & "*", vbDirectory)
     If FilePath <> "" Then
          DirectoryFinder = CurrentProject.Path & "\DataFolder\" & FilePath
     End If
End Function
```

Comment: Ah, I didn't know the Dir() function returned a value!  Thanks, this worked for me using what you've written.

Answer (score 2):

Assign the result of the Dir-function directly to the variable and check if it is empty or not:

```
Dim FilePath As String, BasePath as String
BasePath = CurrentProject.Path & "\DataFolder\"
FilePath = Dir(BasePath & PartialFolderName & "*", vbDirectory)
If FilePath <>"" Then
    ' FilePath now contains the name of the folder that was found.
    ' The full Path would be BasePath & FilePath
    ...
End If
```

Answer (score 2):

Worth noting that `vbDirectory` will find both folders *and* files which match the supplied pattern, so you should consider making sure what you found was a folder and not a file. Also maybe allow for cases where >1 folders match your pattern.

```vb
Sub tester()

    Dim folders As Collection
    
    Set folders = MatchedDirectories("C:\Tester\", "tmp -*")
    Debug.Print folders.Count
    If folders.Count = 0 Then
        'no matches
    ElseIf folders.Count = 1 Then
        'one match
    Else
        'multiple matches
    End If

End Sub

Public Function MatchedDirectories(searchIn As String, PartialFolderName As String) As Collection
     Dim f As String, col As New Collection
     If Right(searchIn, 1) <> "\" Then searchIn = searchIn & "\"
     
     f = Dir(searchIn & PartialFolderName, vbDirectory)
     Do While Len(f) > 0
        'make sure it's a directory we found...
        If GetAttr(searchIn & f) = vbDirectory Then col.Add searchIn & f
        f = Dir()
     Loop
     Set MatchedDirectories = col
End Function
```